# parse and capture the numbers that are at the end of strings

Tags: java, string

I am building a program to go through a log file that has entries like this:

```
en halo%20reach%20noble%20actual%20in%20theater 1 659
en Wazir_Khan_Mosque 2 77859
en Waziristan_War 3 285976
en Wazirpur_Upazila 1 364
```

I want to output the numbers that appear at the end of each string (ie 659, 77859, 285976, 285976, 364). As you can see the numbers have differing amounts of digits.

How can I grab the last numbers from these strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the String according to whitespaces:

```
String[] splitted = myStr.split("\\s+");
```

Then take the last element:

```
splitted[splitted.length - 1];
```

If you want to `int` value, you should use [Integer#parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29).

Another solution is using [lastIndexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) and [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)..

Comment: was writing the same, add `Integer.parseInt()` to complete your answer, if he want to use the int number ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
int pos = line.lastIndexOf(' ');
int value = Integer.parseInt(line.substr(pos+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading each line and assigning to a string like this

```
String line = "en halo%20reach%20noble%20actual%20in%20theater 1 659";
```

then doing this should give you the last number

```
String words[] = line.split("\\s");
System.out.println(words[words.length - 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't recommend regular expressions as they are so often abused here on Stackoverflow ( especially when it comes to XML/HTML ), but this the perfect case to learn how to use them!

Splitting on whitespace, while that will work isn't as robust as this approach; which will continue to work if the whitespace varies, and allows you to capture all the other data in one operation, which you will probably want eventually:

[`^en\s+(.*)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)$`](http://regex101.com/r/gW3vO2) : Click for an explanation of how it works!

Then to use it:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^en\\s+(.*)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\d+)$");
final Matcher m = p.matches("en Wazirpur_Upazila 1 364");
final String g1 = m.group(1); // Wazirpur_Upazila
final String g2 = m.group(2); // 1
final String g3 = m.group(3); // 364
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, may not be very good

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("log.txt"));
try {
    String line = br.readLine();
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    while(line!=null) {
        String[] strsplit = line.split(" ");
        line = br.readLine();
        for(int i=3;i<strsplit.length;i+=4) {
            stringList.add(strsplit[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(stringList);
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```